# How to create an object of class with private constructors?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

If constructors are used for initialization of objects and not the creation of the object then for a class with private constructor why can't we create an object in another class?

```
class Test1 {
    private Test1() {

    }
    void one() {

    }
    Test1 t1=new Test1();
    void two() {
        t1.one();
    }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t1=new Test1();// line 3
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting an error at line 3.

Since the new keyword creates an object and not call to the constructor, is there any way that I can create an object of class Test1?

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor is not visible, you cannot call it from outside.

There are some use-cases for that:

1. Singleton-Pattern - there is only one instance, which is kept in a static member variable.
2. The class only consists of static methods and constants, and there is no use of such instance (like `java.lang.Math`)
3. Instances of that class are created through static factory methods. That gives the author the freedom to refactor the constructors as he wishes, without breaking the public API. Furthermore, he can declare the static method to return a more general interface type instead of the concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

As written in [this article](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-private-constructor-example/):

> The use of private constructor is to serve singleton classes. A
>   singleton class is one which limits the number of objects creation to
>   one. Using private constructor we can ensure that no more than one
>   object can be created at a time. By providing a private constructor
>   you prevent class instances from being created in any place other than
>   this very class.

Take a deeper look at the article, they have examples for the use of private constructors in Java.

Comment: Are private constructors **only** for singleton classes?
I think that you can also use it for classes where you want your instances to be only created through *factory methods*. For example, the class `java.time.Period` has a private constructor but is not a singleton class.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in another situations, like the one you mentioned, but most cases, it follows the singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes, it also makes sense for classes like `java.lang.Math`. It only consists of static methods and constants, so you'll never need an actual instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

The new keyword *does* use the constructor since it is used to initialize the object during creation. If you do not provide any constructors the compiler will insert a default public one. If you provide a constructor, it will not. Even if the provided constructor is private. So, if you provide only a private constructor, you have no way of initializing the class from outside of it's scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the only constructors of a class are private, then other code is not supposed to directly construct it.

(For the pedants, yes you can use reflection (if you can get around Java security), also JNI and there's nested classes.)

The class may provide static creation methods for external code to create instances in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a class with private constructor. private constructor prevents object creation from outside.

In this example we can't create an object of Test1 outside of the same class. ie, we can't create object on the main() method.

If you need to create an object of Test1, it can be implemented inside of the class with the help of a  static method. It is illustrated by [mkjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768967/mkjh)

Answer (score -2):

The `new` keyword does call the class's constructor. If it's private, you won't be able to create a new object from another class.

You have just created a [Singleton](https://codepumpkin.com/singleton-design-pattern/).